# Merger/Acquisition Aggregation Framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following objects and am trying to fund the total amount of funding for a specific industry in 2015.

```
       {
            "_id" : ObjectId("563549877befdba00db4abb2"),
            "acquired_year" : 2015,
            "industry" : "Games",
            "company_info" : {
                "company_name" : "Pinion.gg",
                "price" : ""
            }
        }
```

I wrote this code to group by industry to find the total amount of acquisitions $$ spent for the specific industry, which worked.

```
 db.acquisitions.aggregate([

 { $match: {"acquired_year":{$gte:2015} }  },
 { $project : {"industry":"$company_market", acquired_year:1, "company_info": {"company_name":"$company_name", "price":"$acquistion_price"}}},
 { $group: {"_id":"$industry", "industry_funding":{$sum:"$company_info.price"}}}

 ])
```

Output is...

```
        {
            "_id" : "Semiconductors",
            "industry_funding" : 18861500000
        },
        {
            "_id" : "Coworking",
            "industry_funding" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : "Stock Exchanges",
            "industry_funding" : 365000000
        },
```

I'm trying to figure out how I could also list the top 5 companies with the highest acquisition prices for each industry. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [limit and sort each group by in mongoDB using aggregation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458107/limit-and-sort-each-group-by-in-mongodb-using-aggregation)